# Redefining nodata values into zero in QGIS without changing the other values?

Tags: qgis, raster, reclassify, nodata, qgis-2.18

I have a raster layer with nodata pixels and I want these to be 0. I have tried the SAGA tool "reclassify values", the GDAL "fill nodata" (also with a validity mask containing only zeroes) and the SAGA "close gaps".

My problem is that with all these, the other values are also being changed --for example, the maximum value in my initial raster layer is 32.94 but after the reclassification, the maximum value is 29.4.
I don't understand why the other values are also being transformed!?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange!  A question to clarify; Are you seeing these maximum values (29.4 and 32.94) on the `Layers Panel` and `Layer Properties | Style` perhaps? QGIS usually shows values at 2%/98% quantiles. If it is the case,  you can check real Min/max values by hitting [Load] button after toggle on the  `Min/max` option in the `Load min/max values` on `Layer Properties | Style` tab.

Comment: @Kazuhito thanks for your answer! I checked in the Layer Properties and loaded the min/max values and I saw that they are the same, -thank you for this tip! But obviously, "no data" values are not replaced by 0 but by other arbitrary values, even when I use a 0 value mask. how can I get exclusively zeroes to replace the no data pixels?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Can you add some more information about the other arbitrary value? Is it any particular value?

Comment: the values are between 10 and 20 with "close gaps" and very irregular after I ran "fill nodata" but with the latter, it seems like qgis creates its own new grid with horizontal, vertical and diagonal bands of similar values

Comment: I see. Both "close gaps" and "fill nodata" uses values from nearby cells, most reliable tool would be SAGA "reclassify values" tool for this operation.

Comment: thanks! I tried "reclassify values" a couple of times but I always end up with a raster containing only 0, no matter how I changed the settings before I run it. I for example selected "range", then my min/max values (0/60) and then I tried it with the default value 2 as new value and I tried the other default settings, so for the rest it was 0 and "replace no data values" and "replace other values" were activated. Could you tell me which settings would be correct for only changing no data to 0 ?

Comment: To replace NoData by 0, I will activate only "replace no data values" and  0.000000 as "new value for no data", while de-activate "replace other values". Other options are basically untouched. (Method= [0] single, old value= 0.0, new value= 0.0 <-- I think the default setting of this new value is 1.0).

Comment: it worked! thanks a lot for your help! Appreciate it

Answer (score 3):

QGIS shows min/max values at 2%/98% quantiles by default, and replacing nodata by zero(0), or adding zeros to the dataset, can shift its range.

Let me try to illustrate what (i think) had happened, using a [sample dataset](https://tahoe.usgs.gov/products/dem/tahoedems_dem.zip) taken from [USGS Lake Tahoe Basin](https://tahoe.usgs.gov/DEM.html).

[image]

The above `Layers Panel` shows 2 layers, `Reclassified Grid` which came from SAGA "reclassify values" tool which replaced NoData values of `tahoedems` (original DEM) by zero (0).

We notice its maximum value also changed from 9327.77 to 9275.77.
It is confirmed by Min (0) and Max (9275.77) values on the `Layer properties | Style`. (see below image)

----- Min and Max values (default display) of Reclassifed raster ----

[image]

However, what we are looking at the above image is `Cumulative count cut` (2%~98%).

Changing the setting to `Min/max` and `Accuracy | Actual (slower)` gives us real data range. (0 ~ 10890, as below)

----- Min and Max values (actual range) of Reclassifed raster ----

[image]

This maximum value of the original raster (tahoedems), which range 4616~10890 ft confirms that maximum (10890) remains unchanged.

----- Min and Max values (actual range) of original DEM ----

[image]

The distribution of cell values, which was 4616-10890 originally, was skewed toward lower-side by adding 0-values where there were no data (in other words there were NoData cells). This shifted 2%/98% cumulative count, so it looked as if it changed maximum value, too.